# Is there a multiplex limit for perf_event.h event groups on Pi 3

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi, arm, perf

I am am trying to run some analytics on PMU hardware/cache events on my Pi using `perf_event.h`. **I am getting an error whenever I am attempting to add more than 7 events to an event group.** There are several things I don't understand.

The main questions are as follows:

- Is there a limit to the number of events that can be multiplexed on the Pi (ARM cortex A53 I believe)? Like I said I am failing at 8 and that seems low.
- When multiplexing events, does `perf_event.h` detect the number of PMU counters and utilize all of them?
- If there are limits on number of events in event groups, can I access this information using `perf_event.h` capabilities?
- Do you know of any good resources to help me better understand the functionality of `perf_event.h`?

I am going to include the entire file I am attempting to run because I am new to this and I am not sure which part will be significant. The macros N and M at the top of the code are the number of hw events and hw cache events to use respectively. **The error occurs whenever N+M > 7**

*I believe this code will run on any Linux system (stress package is used `apt-get install stress`)*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/perf_event.h>
#include <linux/hw_breakpoint.h>
#include <asm/unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define N 0 // number of hw events to monitor
#define M 8 // number of hw events to monitor

int global_sigchld_trip = 0; // catch end child
void sighandler(int);

// function to add perf event to event list
// based on example from:
//     http://web.eece.maine.edu/~vweaver/projects/perf_events/perf_event_open.html
static long
perf_event_open(struct perf_event_attr *hw_event, pid_t pid,
                    int cpu, int group_fd, unsigned long flags)
{
    int ret;
    ret = syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, hw_event, 
                    pid, cpu, group_fd, flags);
    return ret;
}

// no function for seeing if we can monitor kernel events
int no_function(int seconds)
{
    sleep(seconds);    
    printf("\n\n Start stress \n\n");
    system("stress -c 4 -t 10");
    return 0;
}



int
main(int argc, char **argv){

    signal(SIGCHLD, sighandler);

    int num_hw_events = N;
    uint pe_hw[7] = {
                        PERF_COUNT_HW_CPU_CYCLES,
                        PERF_COUNT_HW_INSTRUCTIONS,
                        PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_REFERENCES,
                        PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_MISSES,
                        PERF_COUNT_HW_BRANCH_INSTRUCTIONS,
                        PERF_COUNT_HW_BRANCH_MISSES,
                        PERF_COUNT_HW_BUS_CYCLES,
                    };

    char hw_name_arr[7][50] = {
                            "PERF_COUNT_HW_CPU_CYCLES",
                            "PERF_COUNT_HW_INSTRUCTIONS",
                            "PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_REFERENCES",
                            "PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_MISSES",
                            "PERF_COUNT_HW_BRANCH_INSTRUCTIONS",
                            "PERF_COUNT_HW_BRANCH_MISSES",
                            "PERF_COUNT_HW_BUS_CYCLES",
                           };


    // cache events
    int num_hw_cache_events = M;
    uint pe_hw_cache[12] = {
                    (PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_L1D) | (PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_OP_READ << 8) | (PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_RESULT_MISS << 16), // 
                    (PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_L1I) | (PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_OP_READ << 8) | (PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_RESULT_MISS << 16),
                    (PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_LL) | (PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_OP_READ << 8) | (PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_RESULT_MISS << 16),
                    (PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_BPU) | (PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_OP_READ << 8) | (PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_RESULT_MISS << 16),

                    (PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_L1D) | (PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_OP_WRITE<< 8) | (PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_RESULT_MISS << 16), // 
                    (PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_LL) | (PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_OP_WRITE<< 8) | (PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_RESULT_MISS << 16),
                    (PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_BPU) | (PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_OP_WRITE<< 8) | (PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_RESULT_MISS << 16),
                    };

    char hw_cache_name_arr[12][50] = {
                    "PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_L1D_read_miss",
                    "PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_L1I_read_miss",
                    "PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_LL_read_miss",
                    "PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_BPU_read_miss",

                    "PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_L1D_write_miss",
                    "PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_LL_write_miss",
                    "PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_BPU_write_miss",
                    };


    struct perf_event_attr pat_arr[num_hw_events+num_hw_cache_events];

    long long counts[num_hw_events+num_hw_cache_events];
    int fd_arr[num_hw_events+num_hw_cache_events];


    // initialize hw events
    for(int i=0; i<num_hw_events; i++)
    {
        memset(&pat_arr[i], 0, sizeof(struct perf_event_attr));
        pat_arr[i].type = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE;
        pat_arr[i].size = sizeof(struct perf_event_attr);
        pat_arr[i].config = pe_hw[i];
        if(i==0){pat_arr[i].disabled = 1;}
        else{pat_arr[i].disabled = 0;}
        pat_arr[i].exclude_kernel = 1;
        pat_arr[i].exclude_hv = 1;
        pat_arr[i].inherit = 1;

        if(i==0){fd_arr[i] = perf_event_open(&pat_arr[i],0,-1,-1,0);}
        else{fd_arr[i] = perf_event_open(&pat_arr[i],0,-1,fd_arr[0],0);}
        if (fd_arr[i] == -1){
            fprintf(stderr, "Error opening leader %llx\n", pat_arr[i].config);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        printf("FD%d: %d \t ITEM: %s\n",i,fd_arr[i], hw_name_arr[i]);
    }

    // initialize hw cache events
    for(int i=0; i<num_hw_cache_events; i++)
    {
        memset(&pat_arr[i+num_hw_events], 0, sizeof(struct perf_event_attr));
        pat_arr[i+num_hw_events].type = PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE;
        pat_arr[i+num_hw_events].size = sizeof(struct perf_event_attr);
        pat_arr[i+num_hw_events].config = pe_hw_cache[i];
        if(i+num_hw_events==0){printf("dis=1");pat_arr[i+num_hw_events].disabled = 1;}
        else{printf("dis=0");pat_arr[i+num_hw_events].disabled = 0;}
        pat_arr[i+num_hw_events].exclude_kernel = 1;
        pat_arr[i+num_hw_events].exclude_hv = 1;
        pat_arr[i+num_hw_events].inherit = 1;

        if(i+num_hw_events==0){fd_arr[i+num_hw_events] = perf_event_open(&pat_arr[i+num_hw_events],0,-1,-1,0);}
        else{fd_arr[i+num_hw_events] = perf_event_open(&pat_arr[i+num_hw_events],0,-1,fd_arr[0],0);}
        if (fd_arr[i+num_hw_events] == -1){
            printf("\ni: %d\nnhe:%d\n",i,num_hw_events);
            fprintf(stderr, "Error opening leader %llx\n", pat_arr[i+num_hw_events].config);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        printf("FD%d: %d \t ITEM: %s\n",i+num_hw_events,fd_arr[i+num_hw_events], hw_cache_name_arr[i]);
    }


    // reset and enable counters
    for(int i=0; i<num_hw_events+num_hw_cache_events; i++){
        ioctl(fd_arr[i], PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET,0);
        ioctl(fd_arr[i], PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE,0);
    }

/////////////////// ACTION ///////////////////////////

    /*-------- CHILD PROCESS BEING REDORDED -------*/
    printf("\nSHOULD FORK RIGHTE HERE\n");
    pid_t proc = fork();
    if(proc==0){
        printf("entered child process\n");
        int no_sleep = 3;
        no_function(no_sleep);
        //x = silly_events(loop);
        printf("exiting child process\n");
        return 0;
    }
    /*-------- ACTION TAKEN DURRING REDORDING-------*/
    else{
        while(!global_sigchld_trip){
            sleep(1);
            for(int i=0;i<num_hw_events+num_hw_cache_events;i++){read(fd_arr[i], &counts[i], sizeof(long long));}
            for(int i=0;i<num_hw_events+num_hw_cache_events;i++){ioctl(fd_arr[i], PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET,0);}
            for(int i=0;i<num_hw_events;i++){printf("%lld %s\t\n", counts[i], hw_name_arr[i]);}
            printf("--------------------------------------\n");
            for(int i=0;i<num_hw_cache_events;i++){printf("%lld %s\t\n", counts[i+num_hw_events], hw_cache_name_arr[i]);}
            printf("\n\n");
        }
    }


    for(int i=0;i<num_hw_events+num_hw_cache_events;i++){ioctl(fd_arr[i], PERF_EVENT_IOC_DISABLE,0);}
    for(int i=0;i<num_hw_events+num_hw_cache_events;i++){read(fd_arr[i], &counts[i], sizeof(long long));}
    for(int i=0;i<num_hw_events;i++){printf("Used %lld %s\t", counts[i], hw_name_arr[i]);}
    for(int i=0;i<num_hw_cache_events;i++){printf("Used %lld %s\t", counts[i+num_hw_events], hw_cache_name_arr[i]);}
    for(int i=0;i<num_hw_events;i++){close(fd_arr[i]);}
    return 0;
}

void sighandler(int signum) {
   printf("Caught signal %d, coming out...\n", signum);
   global_sigchld_trip = 1;
}
```

Comment: Modern x86 CPUs such as Intel Skylake only have 8 programmable counters per physical core; Linux only lets you use half that many on systems with SMT (Hyperthreading).  On Intel there are also some fixed counters for events like `cycles` and `instructions`; IDK if ARM has some fixed counters as well but this sounds totally reasonable.

Comment: Linux on x86 uses on perf counter for a watchdog timer; on x86 the sysctl is `kernel/nmi_watchdog = 0` to disable that and free up the 8th PMU counter.  Again, ARM might be similar.

Comment: I see, but doesn't perf automatically multiplex events? So you can monitor much more than 8 events simultaneously at the cost of resolution. Is there a limit on the number of events that can be multiplexed on those counters?

Comment: IIRC, the `perf` command-line front-end does the multiplexing, and detects when that's necessary because `perf_event_open` fails.

Comment: @PeterCordes I think I am starting to understand what you mean. A single event group cannot hold more events than the number of counters? Is it possible that I am failing at 7 because I am using all the counters? So I am not actually currently multiplexing at all; is there a way to multiplex withing my C code? If I create multiple event groups will they multiplex automatically?

Comment: Yes, you need to manually tell the kernel what you want it to be counting at any one time.  Then it's all up to you how to aggregate the results, e.g. the way `perf stat` does by showing how much of the time any given event was being monitored at all.

Comment: @PeterCordes, yikes, that sounds tough, but I see what you mean now. That is going to be more involved than I had hoped to get but *so it goes*. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can just fork / exec `perf stat` yourself, with a `-p` option to attach to the right process.  Then kill it with a signal when you want it to stop.  That obviously has more overhead for `perf` startup, but might be good enough.

Comment: I am not using the cmd line utility because I want fine grain control over counter reading and clearing. I may be going about it the wrong way. A little context might help. My interest is applying different machine learning techniques to hw counters to attempt to identify event characteristics of "hot" processes (processes that cause CPU temp to rise more rapidly). I am trying to get measurement of every available counter in some time interval (eg 1 second). I understand that multiplexing will loose resolution, but that is ok as long as it is close.

Comment: 1 second is plenty of time to fork/exec and kill `perf -p getpid()` stat instead of calling `perf_event_open`.  Let it multiplex for you, and collect the results from a text file.  Or write multiplexing code yourself.

Comment: That is a good idea. Letting perf multiplex for me sounds much more appealing for my skill level. Thanks for the advice. Maybe as I understand these things more I will write my own multiplexer.